# Float values when pivoting dataframe of integers (pandas - python)

Tags: python, pandas, sum, pivot-table

I have a huge pandas dataframe, shaped like this example:

```
 new_id hour names values
    0   0   mark    5
    0   0   matt    4
    0   0   alex    3
    1   0   roger   2
    1   0   arthur  7
    1   1   alf     8
    2   1   ale     6
    3   1   peter   5
    3   2   tom     2
    4   2   andrew  7
```

I need to reshape it, so I use `pivot_table()`:

```
dummy=dummy.pivot_table(index=['hour','new_id'],columns='name', values='values').fillna(0)
```

so it becomes

```
        names   ale alex alf andrew arthur mark matt peter roger tom
hour    new_id                                      
0           0   0.0 3.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 5.0 4.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
            1   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 7.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2.0 0.0
1           1   0.0 0.0 8.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
            2   6.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
            3   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 5.0 0.0 0.0
2           3   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2.0
            4   0.0 0.0 0.0 7.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
....
```

By the way, this small example can't reproduce my problem: in the real dataset, when I pivot it, I get some float values which shouldn't be there, since they are the aggregation and the sum of the `values` of the initial dataset, which are all integers. Not only they are float, but they are also quite far from the exact results.

Why do I get these float values? Is there a better way to get what I want? I don't really want to write by myself a function to sum properly all the values before pivoting the dataframe, since this should be exactly what `pivot_table()`does.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is problem `NaN`s, which convert all values to `float`s so possible solution is add parameter `fill_value=0` if input data are `integer`s:

```
dummy=dummy.pivot_table(index=['hour','new_id'],columns='name', values='values', fill_value=0)
print (dummy)
name         ale  alex  alf  andrew  arthur  mark  matt  peter  roger  tom
hour new_id                                                               
0    0         0     3    0       0       0     5     4      0      0    0
     1         0     0    0       0       7     0     0      0      2    0
1    1         0     0    8       0       0     0     0      0      0    0
     2         6     0    0       0       0     0     0      0      0    0
     3         0     0    0       0       0     0     0      5      0    0
2    3         0     0    0       0       0     0     0      0      0    2
     4         0     0    0       7       0     0     0      0      0    0
```

Default aggregate function in [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) is `mean`, so is expected at least one float value in output, so it convert all values to `float`s.

So if change aggregate function to `sum` all working nice:

```
dummy = dummy.pivot_table(index=['hour','new_id'],
                          columns='name', 
                          values='values', 
                          fill_value=0, 
                          aggfunc='sum')
```

Comment: Strangely I get integers on the example dataset but I still get floats on the whole dataframe, don't know why.

Comment: @sato - what is `df.dtypes` of input data?

Comment: For the 'values' column it's int64

Comment: I know, and I really have no idea on how to work around this issue. The only thing I know is that it's giving me completely wrong results. Could it be a good idea to compute the sums before pivoting the dataframe? If so, how could I do this?

Comment: Plus: should I open an issue on pandas github?

Comment: @sato - hmmm, are data condidental? Because maybe data dependent issue...

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I cannot share data. Can you suggest some reason for data to raise issues? What should I look for?

Comment: hmm, hard question, if no float column. What about `pivot_table` alternative? `dummy.groupby(['hour','new_id','name'])['values'].mean().unstack(fill_value=0)`

Comment: Exactly the same: still floats, same results

Comment: @sato - I know what is problem :) You aggregtae by mean, not by sum, so mean are floats :)

Comment: @sato - so need `dummy=dummy.pivot_table(index=['hour','new_id'],columns='name', values='values', fill_value=0, aggfunc='sum')
print (dummy)` or  `dummy.groupby(['hour','new_id','name'])['values'].sum().unstack(fill_value=0)`

Comment: jeeeez, you fooled me with that mean() in the groupby expression :D I copy-pasted quickly and I totally missed it. You're great :D

Comment: @sato - I can get is earlier :) Super, I was really surprised why get it :)

Comment: I really thought that `pivot_table()` used the sum as default function. Write your comment as an answer so I can accept it :)